# How to apply a "Model Wrapper VM" to a User Control which is a collection child?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I need to use a wrapper for my model, because I need to create some "View Only" properties, that I think, doesn't fit in the Model. The problem is, it's a collection member

This is my code snippet to make things clearer. **Even though I didn't write it down completely here (to shorten the code), but I still use** `INotifyPropertyChanged` **correctly in my real code.**

This is my A,B Class Model and MainWindowVM :

```
public class A : INPC
{
    //Some codes
}

public class B : INPC
{
    public ObservableCollection<A> As {get; set;}
}

public class MainWindowVM : INPC
{
    public ObservableCollection<B> Bs {get; set;}
}
```

This is my MainWindow code :

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfA, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <c:B_UserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As we all already know, code above "flow" is : MainWindowVM (VM) -> B (Model) -> A (Model)

But, I need to make it : MainWindowVM (VM) -> [ BVM (VM) -> B (Model) ] -> [ AVM (VM) -> A (Model) ]

Given this AVM and BVM (as "Model Wrapper"):

```
public class AVM : INPC
{
    public A Model {get; set;}

    public AVM (A model) { Model = model; }
}

public class BVM : INPC
{
    public B Model {get; set;}

    public BVM (B model) { Model = model; }
}
```

**How to do it?**

---

**My guess on the solution :**

Change this :

```
public class MainWindowVM : INPC
{
    public ObservableCollection<A> As {get; set;}
}

public class AVM : INPC
{
    public A Model {get; set;}

    public AVM (A model) { Model = model; }
}

public class BVM : INPC
{
    public B Model {get; set;}

    public BVM (B model) { Model = model; }
}
```

Into :

```
public class MainWindowVM : INPC
{
    public ObservableCollection<BVM> BVMs {get; set;}
}

public class AVM : INPC
{
    public A Model {get; set;}

    public AVM (A model) { Model = model; }
}

public class BVM : INPC
{
    public B Model {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<AVM> AVMs {get; set;} //This is the Binding Property from the UserControl's ItemsControl (code similar to the MainWindow one)

    public BVM (B model) { Model = model; //Then Initialize AVMs, based on Collection of As in B Model }
}
```

**Is my answer already correct, or is there any more appropriate answer? (Without using** `DependencyProperty` **)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When wrapping a model class in a data type view model, it is customary to wrap *each property* so that you can implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the wrapper class. Your model classes are supposed to represent your business objects, so you shouldn't implement the `NotifyPropertyChanged` interface there. Therefore, your wrapper class would then look more like this:

```
public class AVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private A model;

    public AVM(A model) { this.model = model; }

    public string SomeStringProperty
    {
        get { return model.SomeStringProperty; }
        set
        {
            model.SomeStringProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeStringProperty"); 
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: i see. Aside from the INPC thing you mentioned, the rest of my code is correct then?? Just to make sure.

Comment: It seems ok... why not just try it out and find out?

Comment: I mean fundamentally. Not the matter of error or not. Sorry for not elaborating it. Thanks tho